# What to do with a closed and deleted question I've already answered?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-undelete

About a month ago a user asked a question that was not well-received by the community, though it was (IMHO) a legitimate question.

I've answered the question and tried to counter-vote the downvotes that question got (however, I'm only one person so I have only one vote).

After I've posted my answer the question was closed as "unclear what you're asking" (when IMHO it was clear even in its first version), and of course I've voted to reopen. Soon later the question was deleted by the community (and again, I voted to undelete).

Now here is the dilemma:
On one hand, the question itself is not that bad, but it's not great either, and it has a score of -7 (-12, +5) - so undeleting it will have a positive impact on the OP's reputation (+26 points total), but a negative impact on the OP's questions score.

On the other hand, my answer to this question can help other developers and save them the time I've spent solving a problem with one of my old projects (that took me almost two days to figure out the problem and solve it).

So, should I ask 10k+ users to undelete and reopen it, should I just write a new, self-answered question, that might not get as many views as the current question and answer, or should I just forget about the entire thing?

Please note that this is not a reputation pursue - though my answer was upvoted I can live perfectly fine without thous extra points - I really think that the question and answer can help other users facing the same problems. If it helps another developer save at least some of the time it took me, then I think it's worth having on Stack Overflow.

Having said that, here's the link to the question:

*[How many controls can I create and show in a Windows Forms form?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52944471)*

Comment: I don't care much about vote. So I won't post a self-answerd question. I look at those not great question knowing that even if the word choosen are not exact and do not describe the issue, when you know the solution. But people encontering the issue will use this weird, naive way to describe the issue. Advance user will downvote because it's basic or little unclear, While people facing the issue will hit it like 1rst match on google. I will go with edit , while keeping the naive description and comprehension. And vote re open. But I didn't unlock this power yet, So I would not follow my advice

Comment: -12,+5 is a pretty major controversy.  Hard to see how that happened when you don't link the question.  Yes, show us.

Comment: @DragandDrop the votes are not the real issue here, It was a mistake on my part - wanted to write views. Edited.

Comment: @HansPassant I know, but I hesitated to post the link because while the question is heavily downvoted, my answer was upvoted . It's not a reputation pursue and I suspected this question would look like it is if I posted the link. Having said that, I guess it could help understand the controversy of the question, so here it is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52944471/how-many-controls-can-i-create-and-show-in-a-windows-form

Comment: I don't get it, -12 for that?  It is an eminently practical question that could benefit any newbie [winforms] programmer.  Sadly he asked for the absolute limit and not the practical one.  Well, doesn't know the difference yet.  I edited the question, it does invalidate your answer a bit.  Sorry about that.  "About 50" is the practical answer.

Comment: @Hans thanks, but I think your edit, while might be what the OP actually wants, is changing the question to a completely different one, and for that we already have answers in the link posted in a comment by CodeCaster to that question: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/851553/upper-reasonable-limit-to-number-of-user-control-instances](Upper (reasonable) limit to number of user control instances). Also, It's totally possible to create many controls and only have some of them visible at any given moment, which also would potentially break the 10,000 user objects limit...

Comment: I'd leave it as a hard limit question, I somewhat disagree with making it a practical one. UX can vary wildly depending on what you're doing exactly, if you're using a tab control and only displaying a fraction of the controls on the form, 50 might be well below practical. If you're talking about UX, you'd probably need to rewrite it to _visible at one moment_, and that's a very different question

Comment: @Hans also, the original text of the question was "I'm developing a C# Winforms application, and I want to what is the maximum number of controls that I can create and show in a windows form? " No mention of UX - that was my attempt of salvaging the question...

Comment: Funny how it turned controversial again :)  Okay, I give up.

Comment: It's pretty hard to *know* that the quesrion is answerable before it's answered, right?

Answer (score 7):

**Leave it as it is.**

The community already decided that question isn't good enough (by downvoting it).

You may disagree with this decision, but it is how democracy works. It is impossible to make everyone happy.

From a practical perspective, if you really think that solution you found is worth to be on this site **you can create you own question and answer it.**

If problem was in how question was presented and not the problem itself people will vote fore it.

Comment: I guess I could re-write the question, already tried that by editing it. The point is that if I do re-write it, I have two choices - either make it a question about the particular problem I've encountered, which will make more sense with the answer I've posted but would not address the original question so much, or by re-writing basically the same content, which I fear would be a waist of time and storage.

Comment: @ZoharPeled or you can rewrite it in more generic way. The way it will fit for more people. You may present generic problem and add your specific example. Do same in your answer. Give generic answer and illustrate it by solving problem from example.

Comment: Nit: Stack Overflow is not a democracy.

Comment: @Makoto Hail our benevolent dictators for life.

Comment: @ZoharPeled if you decide to go self-answer route I'd go for "make it a question about the particular problem I've encountered" - it is so much easier to create self-answered question that way rather than starting from generic one. You also know that at least one other person had similar problem making your new question at least somewhat useful... (it may be good idea to re-read some existing self-answer guidance on meta in advance :) )

Comment: At the first revision the question was terrible, and improved later. This is not a good choice (otherwise how can questions ever improve?)